# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x10)

Tags: cocoa, debugging

In my OS X app, I'm trying to save and retrieve the tag of a radio button. The error occurs on the line marked "<-HERE" in setPreferenceRotor. There is a valid tag coming in.

```
//  PreferenceController.h
extern NSString * const myCellKey;
extern NSString * const myMatrixChangedNotification;

@interface PreferenceController:NSWindowController
{
  IBOutlet NSMatrix *matrixRotor;
}
- (IBAction)setRotorTag:(id)sender;
+ (NSInteger)preferenceRotorTag;
+ (void)setPreferenceRotor:(NSInteger)matrixTag;
@end

//  PreferenceController.m
NSString * const myMatrixChangedNotification = @"myRotorChanged";
@implementation PreferenceController
- (void)windowDidLoad
  {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    [matrixRotor selectCellWithTag:[PreferenceController preferenceRotorTag]];
  }
+ (NSInteger)preferenceRotorTag
  {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *tagAsData = [defaults objectForKey:myCellKey];
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tagAsData];
  }
+ (void)setPreferenceRotor:(NSInteger)matrixTag
  {
    //NSInteger mt = matrixTag;
    NSData *tagAsData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:matrixTag]; **//<-HERE**
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:tagAsData forKey:myCellKey];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a primitive (non-object) value, of type `NSInteger` from variable `matrixTag`, to a method, `archivedDataWithRootObject:`, which expects an object reference value. That method happily tries to use the value (which is probably the integer 16, `0x10`) as an object reference, and kaboom...

Your thinking looks correct, you know you cannot store non-object values in user defaults, and so you must wrap them as objects first. It is just your way of doing so that is wrong. What you need here is to create an instance of `NSNumber` from your integer. You could write:

```
NSNumber *tagAsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:matrixTag];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tagAsNumber forKey:myCellKey];
```

However this pattern is common enough that a shortcut is provided:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:matrixTag forKey:myCellKey];
```

and this will create the `NSNumber` object for you. There is also a corresponding `integerForKey:` method which will unwrap the integer for you when reading.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and even better a very good explanation!